# How to return first json element with Laravel API feature?

Tags: json, laravel

About this code, define an API endpoint to get post detail:

/posts/{post}

```
 public function show($post)
 {
     return DB::table('posts')->where('id', $post)->get()->map(function($s){
         $s->type = __(Post::TEXT[$s->type]);
         return $s;
     });
 }
```

It return json like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test"
  }
]
```

Want to return data like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test"
}
```

So added `->first()` to the end of the method:

```
 public function show($post)
 {
     return DB::table('posts')->where('id', $post)->get()->map(function($s){
         $s->type = __(Post::TEXT[$s->type]);
         return $s;
     })->first();
 }
```

But got error:

```
(1/1) UnexpectedValueException
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.
```

How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that an api route correctly returns a json response, use the [json response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#json-responses) helper. This will try to parse any data and add the correct headers.

```
public function show($post)
{
    $post = DB::table('posts')->where('id', $post)->get()->map(function ($s) {
        $s->type = __(Post::TEXT[$s->type]);
        return $s;
    })->first()

    return response()->json($post);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instead of returning just the map function result, you can cast that into an object like this: 
`$result = DB::...
return (object) $result;`